# Derivative of $f(x)=x^2 \cos \frac 1 x$ using the definition

Tags: limits, derivatives

How can I find the derivative of $f(x)=x^2  \cos \frac 1 x$ using the definition of a derivative at $x = 0$?

I tried as

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h = \frac{(x+h)^2 \cos \frac 1 {x+h} } h =\frac 1 h (x^2 + 2xh + h^2)  \cos \frac 1 {x+h}$.

But if I try substituting $h \to 0$ then the function becomes $\infty$

How to find the derivative at $x = 0$? Sorry for not being clear earlier, I'm still learning to present the question here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We do not make a habit of answering questions where no effort is shown by the OP, nor simply doing homework. Try including what you've tried so far, and adding a bit of context to your question, so others are more willing to help. 
Your function, as you've written it, is undefined at $0$. Are you leaving it like that, or you meant to define $f(0)=0$? Further, at which point are you trying to calculate the derivative?

Comment: Also, I think you may have accidentally forgot to subtract f(x) from the nummerator of your fraction.

Comment: You can't, unless you tell how $f$ is defined at $0$, which is not at all obvious; a function cannot have a derivative where it is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using First derivative $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(x+h)^2\cos \left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)-x^2\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{h}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}x^2\cdot \frac{\cos \left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(h+2x)}{h}\cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \cos C-\cos D = -2\sin \left(\frac{C+D}{2}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{C-D}{2}\right)$$ for first part.

So $$\displaystyle f'(x) = -\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}x^2\cdot \left[\sin \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x+h}+\frac{1}{x}}{2}\right)\cdot \sin \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}}{2}\right)\right]\cdot \frac{1}{h}+2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

So $$\displaystyle f'(x) = -x^2\cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sin \left(\frac{-h}{2(x^2+xh)}\right)\cdot \frac{2(x^2+xh)}{-h}\cdot \frac{-1}{2(x^2+xh)}+2x\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

So we get $$\displaystyle f'(x)=x^2\cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x^2}+2x\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I let:

$$ y=f(x)=x^2\cos(1/x) $$

then let,

$$ u=x^2 $$ so $$ du/dx=2x $$ and $$ v=\cos(1/x) $$

so using the chain rule $$dv/dx=-\sin(1/x)*-1/x^2$$ $$dv/dx=1/x^2.\sin(1/x)$$

Then applying the product rule: $dy/dx=v*du/dx+u*dv/dx$,

$$f'(x)=2x\cos(1/x)+x^2.1/x^2\sin(1/x)=2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)$$

$$f'(x)=2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x)$$

Checking with wolfram alpha: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28%28x^2%29cos%281%2Fx%29%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%28%28x%5E2%29cos%281%2Fx%29%29)

Comment: The question was asking for the derivative "using the definition of a derivative"

Comment: Ah yes, my fault!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you put $f(0)=0$ to make $f$ continuous there, you have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} =  \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h^2\cos(1/h)}{h} =  \lim_{h\to0} h \cos \frac1h = 0
$$
since $|\cos \frac1h| \le 1$ and $h \to 0$.

Comment: The right answer.

Comment: @egreg In defence of the other answerers, the question was edited to make it clear that $x=0$ was the point of interest.